# Opening an url in a new tab instead of a popup (after click)

Tags: javascript

The user clicks a context-menu to create a new item, the item is saved async and a url is opened in a new tab when save is done. Thats what I want but Chrome is opening the url in a popup instead of a new tab. When opening the window outside the saveasync-then-handler it works fine (the commented code), but not inside. Anything I can do get the same behaviour inside the handler? I have tried using open.bind(this) but that didn't help...

```
var open = function() {
  var win = window.open('/page', '_blank');
  win.focus();
};

client.SaveAsync().then(open); // This doesn't work, opens in a popup window

open(); // This works, opens in a new tab
```

Comment: By "popup" do you mean a new window. If so this is a browser settings issue and not one you can solve programmatically.

Comment: A popup as in a new windows yes. I know I can't force it to open in a tab or window at will, but it seems that a tab is opened whenever window.open is called within a mouse click event handler, which is in my case. But my async-then-handler seem to break this behaviour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the same issue, it's browser protection.
Managed to solve it with a workaround:

```
var win = window.open('/page', '_blank');
client.SaveAsync().then(function() {
    win.open('/page', '_self');
});
```

The trick is that it works when it's not inside an async request like a response of a http request, so we open it before the request and redirect it after we get the response.